# Help implementing Java Pdf-renderer example into SWT?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, swt, pdfrenderer

I'm trying to implement the following code in SWT and I'm not having much luck. Could someone give me a hint on how to use the Pdf-Render library with SWT? I think the main issue is I can't work out how to attach a PagePanel to an SWT shell.

```
package pdfpaneltest;

import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage;
import com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * An example of using the PagePanel class to show PDFs. For more advanced
 * usage including navigation and zooming, look ad the 
 * com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer class.
 *
 * @author joshua.marinacci@sun.com
 */
public class Main {

    public static void setup() throws IOException {

        //set up the frame and panel
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PagePanel panel = new PagePanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //load a pdf from a byte buffer
        File file = new File("test.pdf");
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
            0, channel.size());
        PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);

        // show the first page
        PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(0);
        panel.showPage(page);

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main.setup();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Taken from https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/examples.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...or you may have a look at jPodRenderer which supports SWT... (GPL)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Swing/ SWT bridge. There is a [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) on eclipse.org.

Answer (score 0):

It you have some money to spend, try PdfONE, which is faster and also can cope with enbedded fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siEclipse.php which is a free PDF viewer plugin for Eclipse. You can download the Open Source code including the full workspace project.